# Efficient by-hand loop unrolling

Tags: c, optimization, loops, unroll

I have this C code:

```
for (k = 0; k < n_n; k++) {
    if (k == i || k == j) continue;
    dd=q2_vect[k]-q1_vect;
    d2=dd*dd;
    if (d2<0) {
        a=1;
        break;
    }       
}
```

For compiler optimization reasons (on the SPE of the Cell processor), I need to unloop this by hand, so I tried:

```
dd=q2_vect[0]-q1_vect;
d2=dd*dd;
if (d2<0)goto done;

dd=q2_vect[1]-q1_vect;
d2=dd*dd;
if (d2<0)goto done;

dd=q2_vect[2]-q1_vect;
d2=dd*dd;
if (d2<0)goto done;

.....
.....

// end
goto notdone;

done: 
ok=0;

notdone:
.....
```

but I do not know how to deal with the

```
if (k == i || k == j) continue;
```

and with the fact that the lopp depends on each run on "n_n", and by hand I should write the code so many times as the maximal value "n_n" would get.

How do you think it can be fixed?

Comment: The sequence `if d2<0` is invalid C.

Comment: And even if you add the necessary parentheses, a good compiler will optimize out the whole if statement because the C language defines no conditions under which it could be true. (The code seems to be trying to rely on undefined behavior.)

Comment: not right: `dd == _Imaginary_I` -> `dd*dd == -1.0` and that's valid C.

Comment: sorry, I misstyped, it is d2>0

Comment: So you're looking for the first index other than `i` or `j` where `d2` is not zero? Why are you doing multiplication to get `d2` in the first place? The condition then is equivalent to `q2_vect[k]!=q1_vect`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the code as written is correct? The current code has undefined behavior if `dd` is a signed integer type, and the condition in the if is never satisfied if `d2` is unsigned or if `dd` and `d2` are floating point types. It looks like you're doing a broken search for the first index `k` other than `i` or `j` where squaring the expression `q2_vect[ k]-q1_vect` overflows.

As for efficiently skipping the `i` and `j` iterations, I would instead just look at where the unrolled "loop" stopped, and restart it at `k+1` if `k` was equal to `i` or `j`. This is assuming the code in your loop has no side effects/running total, which is true as written, but I expect you might have meant for the code to do something else (like summing the squares).

Finally, I am *highly* skeptical of your wish to unroll the loop manually when you don't even seem to have working code to begin with. Any good compiler can unroll the loop for you, but often the type of loop unrolling you're looking to do makes performance worse rather than better. I think you'd do better getting your code to work correctly first, then measuring (and looking at the compiler-generated asm), and only trying to improve on that *after* you've determined there's a problem.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler will unroll this loop automatically? Unless n_n is a constant, I think a compiler will have a hard time determining how to unroll it.

Comment: Condition may be satisfied (wuthout undefined behaviour) if dd is `_Imaginary` and d2 is of real type. :)

Comment: Fully unrolling a loop is almost never useful. Instead the compiler might unroll it to perform 8 or 16 iterations per run, and handle the tail with a construct similar to duff's device.

Comment: @Vovanium: haha fair enough. Wish I could give you more than +1 for noticing that. Is OP really using complex types though??

Comment: @R..: This of course very unlikely that author rely on imaginary numbers, but many's belief that x*x>=0 is not true. I i'm angry. :)

Comment: sorry for the "if" mistake (I wrote it fast) and the (d2<0), it is (d2>0)

Answer (score 1):

This code as written is fairly unsuitable for SPEs since it's so branch-heavy. Also, information on the types of the variables involved would help; the test as written seems fairly obscure (even with the `>0` fix), but the code looks like it might be C++ using some sort of vector class that overloads `operator -` to mean vector subtraction and `operator *` of two vectors to compute a dot product.

The first thing to do with such simple loops on SPEs is to get them branch-free (at least the inner loop; i.e. unroll a couple of times and only check for early exit every N iterations) and use SIMD instructions: SPEs *only have SIMD instructions*, so not using SIMD processing in your loops instantly wastes 75% of your available register space and computational power. Similarly, SPEs can only load aligned qwords (16 bytes) at a time, using smaller data types requires extra work to shuffle the contents of registers around so that the value you're trying to load ends up in the "preferred slot".

You get rid of the `if (k == i || k == j)` by rewriting the first part of the loop using the following branch-free form (this is pseudocode. It's immediately applicable for ints, but you'll need to use intrinsics to get bitwise ops on floats):

```
dd = q2_vect[k] - q1_vect;
d2 = dd * dd;
d2 &= ~(cmp_equal(k, i) | cmp_equal(k, j));
```

Here, `cmp_equal` corresponds to the respective SPE intrinsics (semantics: `cmp_equal(a,b) == (a == b) ? ~0u : 0`). This forces `d2` to zero when `k == i` or `k == j`.

To avoid the `if (d2 > 0)` branch in the inner loop, do the following:

```
a |= cmp_greater(d2, 0);
```

and only check if `a` is nonzero (to early-out) every few loop iterations. If all values computed for `d2` are nonnegative (will be the case if your type is ints, floats or a real-valued vector class), you can simplify this further. Just do:

```
a |= d2;
```

In the end, `a` will only be nonzero if all of the individual terms were nonzero. But be careful with integer overflows (if you're using ints) and NaNs (if you're using floats). If you have to handle these cases, the above simplification will break the code.

Comment: +1 for SIMD. It's worth noting that if you vectorize the loop, `k` will have different values in each element when you compare it against `i` and `j`, e.g. it will start at {0,1,2,3} and increment by {4,4,4,4} each time through. Also, the `spu_orx` ("OR across") intrinsic might be useful here for checking if any of the comparison results are set.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you need to not "execute" the loop body when the condition is met. For this particular problem, you can just place the logical negation of that condition inside the `if` statement's condition.

Normally unrolling is by a factor; the unrolled code still lives in a loop (unless the loop bounds are known to be very small). Furthermore, you'll need to do the "remainder" of the work (corresponding to the remainder of the problem size divided by the unroll factor) outside the loop.

So, an example of loop unrolling:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) do_something(i);
```

can be unrolled by a factor of 2 to:

```
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i += 2) { do_something(i); do_something(i+1); }
for (; i < n; ++i) do_something(i);
```

where the second loop does the "remainder" (it also sets `i` to be the same thing as the unrolled loop would have, but if `i` is not needed after this, the whole line can just be `if (i < n) etc` for this case).

Answer (score 0):

assuming n_n is a compile-time constant, the loop may be trivially unrolled like so:

```
do
{ 
  k=0
  if (k == i || k == j) 
    ;
  else
  {
    dd=q2_vect[ k]-q1_vect;
    d2=dd*dd;
    if (d2<0)
    {
      a=1;
      break;
    }
  }

  k=1
  if (k == i || k == j) 
    ;
  else
  {
    dd=q2_vect[ k]-q1_vect;
    d2=dd*dd;
    if (d2<0)
    {
      a=1;
      break;
    }
  }

  /* and so on, n_n times */

  k= n_n-1
  if (k == i || k == j) 
    ;
  else
  {
    dd=q2_vect[ k]-q1_vect;
    d2=dd*dd;
    if (d2<0)
    {
      a=1;
      break;
    }
  }

} while (0);
```

essentially, everything after the continue goes into the `else` portion of an if statement

Edit: since `n_n` is not a compile time constant, you can still unroll the loop by doing several runs through the loop in a loop, and then finish with a switch-case statement.  in fact, you can combine them like so, this is called the [Duff's device.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

```
#define LOOP_BODY              \
do{                            \  
  if (k == i || k == j)        \
    ;                          \
  else                         \
  {                            \
    dd=q2_vect[ k]-q1_vect;    \
    d2=dd*dd;                  \
    if (d2<0)                  \
    {                          \
      a=1;                     \
      break;                   \
    }                          \
  } while (0)          


k = 0;
switch(n_n % 8)
{
  case 0: for (; k < n_n; k++) { LOOP_BODY; k++; 
  case 7:                        LOOP_BODY; k++;
  case 6:                        LOOP_BODY; k++;
  case 5:                        LOOP_BODY; k++;
  case 4:                        LOOP_BODY; k++;
  case 3:                        LOOP_BODY; k++;
  case 2:                        LOOP_BODY; k++;    
  case 1:                        LOOP_BODY; k++;}
}
```

Comment: the problem is: n_n is a runtime value, given input by user. How can I at the same time unroll the loop by-hand n_n times if I do not know the value?

Answer (score 0):

Usually loop unrolling means making the loop contain a few iterations, such that it is run fewer times.  For example,

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

could be unrolled to

```
i=0;
if(count%2==1) {
    printf("%d", i);
    i=1;
}
while(i<count) {
    printf("%d", i);
    printf("%d", i+1);
    i+=2;
}
```

Comment: what I do not understand or see here, is how can the compiler optimize it

Answer (score 0):

Unrolling this loop will not help here much. Inner loop software unrolling helps with software pipelining of instructions to achieve higher IPC at run-time. Here it could corrupt the logic by unrolling.